# how to manage c files dependencies in make

Tags: c, makefile, dependencies

i'm starting with make and i was searching how to automaticly generate dependencies for my c files, i found this piece of code :

```
# pull in dependency info for *existing* .o files
-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)


# compile and generate dependency info
%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $*.c -o $*.o
    gcc -MM $(CFLAGS) $*.c > $*.d
```

what i don't understand is when i generate the dependencies file %.d, i already have built the %.o file, so what it the point to creating this dependencies file, and the -include i executed before everything so no dependencies file will exist.

Comment: I would not start with make. It is old technology. Try SCOS/Gradle/..  it better for your health

Comment: For first compilation, dependencies doesn't matter - you have to compile everything anyway. They help you on subsequent re-compilations, to determine which files are *required* to be recompiled. It greatly speeds up incremental build, when most of files are already compiled, and you changed only a few.

Comment: @EdHeal Totally agree. Here's how I manage dependencies with Rake: http://www.electronvector.com/blog/using-gcc-for-automatic-c-language-dependency-management-with-rake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-include` means to include the dep file if it is there but not fail if it isn't.

The trick, and this is common in `make` dependency tracking, is that your dependencies are actually one build out of date. You're including, if they are there, the dependency files that were built the last time around.

This is not a problem because for dependencies to change, changes have to be made to something that the target depended on during the last build -- so even though make doesn't know the full new dependencies, it knows that it has to rebuild the target (and generate a new dependency file in the process).

Addendum: By the way, gcc and clang have a `-MD` option that can generate a dependency file while building the `.o` (by default with a `.d` suffix). This means that you can do automatic dependency tracking with implicit rules and cut down your Makefile to the bare minimum like so (for a simple project with `.c` files in a flat directory):

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

# name of the binary to build
TARGET   = target

CC       = gcc

# These flags are used by the implicit rules for C preprocessor flags,
# C compiler flags, linker flags, and libraries to link (-lfoo options)
# -MD in CPPFLAGS means that the implicit rules for .o files will also
# generate a corresponding .d file that contains the dependencies.
# The values here are just examples (thank you, Rear Admiral Obvious!)
CPPFLAGS = -MD -I somewhere/include
CFLAGS   = -O2 -g
LDFLAGS  = -L somewhere/lib
LDLIBS   = -lsomelibrary

# SRCS is a list of all .c files in the directory, the other two are
# pattern substitution expressions that take SRCS and replace the .c with .o
# and .d, respectively
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
DEPS = $(OBJS:.o=.d)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)

# Look, Ma, no explicit rules for .o files!

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

.PHONY: all clean

# include dep files (if available).
-include $(DEPS)
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually add phony target `depend`, like this:

```
depend: $(SOURCES)
        makedepend -Y. $(CFLAGS) $^ 2>/dev/null
```

and run `make depend` time to time to update depenencies.
See `man makedepend` for details.